# How to put file in boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, ipc

How to put a file with an arbitrary name and arbitrary size into a `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory`?

Note, I donot mean `boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file` or
`boost::interprocess::file_mapping`.

I chose `managed_shared_memory` because other options require a fixed file name
to be specified but I need to transfer files with different names.

I need to use boost, not Win32 API.

I rummaged through a huge amount of information on the Internet, but did not
find anything suitable.

Therefore, I am asking you for help. I would be very grateful to you.

Comment: You need to "transfer files" - can you explain what you mean by that? Shared memory doesn't sound like a logical choice altogether. Note that filesystems are already an interprocess-shared resource, so maybe you should just copy the files somewhere shared?

Answer (score 2):

> #### UPDATE
>
> Added bonus versions at the end. Now this answer presents three complete versions of the code:
>
> 1. Using `managed_shared_memory` as requested
> 2. Using `message_queue` as a more natural appraoch for upload/transfter
> 3. Using TCP sockets (Asio) as to demonstrate the flexibilities of that
>
> All of these are using Boost only

Shared memory managed segments contain arbitrary objects. So you define an object like

```
 struct MyFile {
     std::string _filename;
     std::vector<char> _contents;
 };
```

And store it there. But, wait, not so quick, because these can only be stored safely with **interprocess allocators**, so adding some magic sauce (a.k.a lots of interesting typedefs to get the allocators declared, and some constructors):

```
namespace Shared {
    using Mem = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using Mgr = Mem::segment_manager;

    template <typename T>
    using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Mgr>>;

    template <typename T> using Vector = bc::vector<T, Alloc<T>>;
    using String =
        bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

    struct MyFile {
        using allocator_type = Alloc<char>;

        template <typename It>
        explicit MyFile(std::string_view name, It b, It e, allocator_type alloc)

        String _filename;
        Vector<char> _contents;
    };
}
```

Now you can store your files like:

```
Shared::Mem shm(bip::open_or_create, "shared_mem", 10ull << 30);

std::ifstream ifs("file_name.txt", std::ios::binary);
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> data_begin{ifs}, data_end{};

auto loaded = shm.find_or_construct<Shared::MyFile>("file1")(
        file.native(), data_begin, data_end,
         shm.get_segment_manager());
```

> Note that the shared memory won't actually take 30GiB right away, even though
> that's what `10ull << 30` specifies. On most operating systems this will be
> sparesely allocated and only the pages that contain data will be commited.

### Improving

You might have wondered what the `scoped_allocator_adaptor` was for. It doesn't seem we use it?

Well, the idea was to *not* use `find_or_construct` directly per file, but to
store a `Vector<MyFile` so you can harness the full power of BIP allocators.

The following full demo can be invoked

- with filename arguments, which will all be loaded (if they exist as
  regular files)
- without arguments, which will list previously loaded files

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/113f8ad5b1177c6e)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp> // for COLIRU
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace bc = boost::container;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

namespace Shared {
#ifdef COLIRU
    using Mem = bip::managed_mapped_file; // managed_shared_memory not allows
#else
    using Mem = bip::managed_shared_memory;
#endif
    using Mgr = Mem::segment_manager;

    template <typename T>
    using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Mgr>>;

    template <typename T> using Vector = bc::vector<T, Alloc<T>>;
    using String = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

    struct MyFile {
        using allocator_type = Alloc<char>;

        MyFile(MyFile&&) = default;
        MyFile(MyFile const& rhs, allocator_type alloc)
            : _filename(rhs._filename.begin(), rhs._filename.end(), alloc),
              _contents(rhs._contents.begin(), rhs._contents.end(), alloc) {}

        MyFile& operator=(MyFile const& rhs) {
            _filename.assign(rhs._filename.begin(), rhs._filename.end());
            _contents.assign(rhs._contents.begin(), rhs._contents.end());
            return *this;
        }

        template <typename It>
        explicit MyFile(std::string_view name, It b, It e, allocator_type alloc)
            : _filename(name.data(), name.size(), alloc),
              _contents(b, e, alloc) {}

        String _filename;
        Vector<char> _contents;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyFile const& mf) {
            return os << "Name: " << std::quoted(mf._filename.c_str())
                      << " content size: " << mf._contents.size();
        }
    };
} // namespace Shared

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Shared::Mem shm(bip::open_or_create, "shared_mem", 512ull << 10);

    using FileList = Shared::Vector<Shared::MyFile>;
    auto& shared_files =
        *shm.find_or_construct<FileList>("FileList")(shm.get_segment_manager());

    if (1==argc) {
        std::cout << "Displaying previously loaded files: \n";
        for (auto& entry : shared_files)
            std::cout << entry << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Loading files: \n";
        for (auto file : std::vector<fs::path>{argv + 1, argv + argc}) {
            if (is_regular_file(file)) {
                try {
                    std::ifstream ifs(file, std::ios::binary);
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> data_begin{ifs}, data_end{};

                    auto& loaded = shared_files.emplace_back(
                        file.native(), data_begin, data_end);

                    std::cout << loaded << std::endl;
                } catch (std::system_error const& se) {
                    std::cerr << "Error: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
                } catch (std::exception const& se) {
                    std::cerr << "Other: " << se.what() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When run with

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lrt -DCOLIRU
./a.out main.cpp a.out
./a.out
```

Prints

```
Loading files: 
Name: "main.cpp" content size: 3239
Name: "a.out" content size: 175176
Displaying previously loaded files: 
Name: "main.cpp" content size: 3239
Name: "a.out" content size: 175176
```

### BONUS

In response to the comments, I think it's worth actually comparing

#### Message Queue version

For comparison, here's a message queue implementation

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10f5dde5281c0f41)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using bip::message_queue;
static constexpr auto MAX_FILENAME_LENGH = 512; // 512 bytes max filename length
static constexpr auto MAX_CONTENT_SIZE = 512ull << 10; // 512 KiB max payload size

struct Message {
    std::vector<char> _buffer;

    using Uint32 = boost::endian::big_uint32_t;
    struct header_t {
        Uint32 filename_length;
        Uint32 content_size;
    };
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<header_t> and
                  std::is_trivial_v<header_t>);

    Message() = default;

    Message(fs::path file) {
        std::string const name = file.native();
        std::ifstream ifs(file, std::ios::binary);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> data_begin{ifs}, data_end{};

        _buffer.resize(header_len + name.length());
        std::copy(begin(name), end(name), _buffer.data() + header_len);
        _buffer.insert(_buffer.end(), data_begin, data_end);
        header().filename_length = name.length();
        header().content_size    = size() - header_len - name.length();
    }

    Message(char const* buf, size_t size) 
        : _buffer(buf, buf+size) {}

    static constexpr auto header_len = sizeof(header_t);
    static constexpr auto max_size =
        header_len + MAX_FILENAME_LENGH + MAX_CONTENT_SIZE;

    char const* data() const { return _buffer.data(); } 
    size_t size() const      { return _buffer.size(); } 

    header_t& header() {
        assert(_buffer.size() >= header_len);
        return *reinterpret_cast<header_t*>(_buffer.data());
    }

    header_t const& header() const {
        assert(_buffer.size() >= header_len);
        return *reinterpret_cast<header_t const*>(_buffer.data());
    }

    std::string_view filename() const { 
        assert(_buffer.size() >= header_len + header().filename_length);
        return { _buffer.data() + header_len, header().filename_length };
    }

    std::string_view contents() const {
        assert(_buffer.size() >=
                header_len + header().filename_length + header().content_size);

        return {_buffer.data() + header_len + header().filename_length,
            header().content_size};
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Message const& mf) {
        return os << "Name: " << std::quoted(mf.filename())
                  << " content size: " << mf.contents().size();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    message_queue mq(bip::open_or_create, "file_transport", 10, Message::max_size);

    if (1==argc) {
        std::cout << "Receiving uploaded files: \n";
        char rawbuf [Message::max_size];
        while (true) {
            size_t n;
            unsigned prio;
            mq.receive(rawbuf, sizeof(rawbuf), n, prio);

            Message decoded(rawbuf, n);
            std::cout << "Received: " << decoded << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Loading files: \n";
        for (auto file : std::vector<fs::path>{argv + 1, argv + argc}) {
            if (is_regular_file(file)) {
                try {
                    Message encoded(file);
                    std::cout << "Sending: " << encoded << std::endl;

                    mq.send(encoded.data(), encoded.size(), 0);
                } catch (std::system_error const& se) {
                    std::cerr << "Error: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
                } catch (std::exception const& se) {
                    std::cerr << "Other: " << se.what() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A demo:

[image]

> Note that there is a filesize limit in this approach because messages have a maximum length

#### TCP Socket Version

Here's a TCP socket implementation.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/973a2d92645665ca)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
static constexpr auto MAX_FILENAME_LENGH = 512; // 512 bytes max filename length
static constexpr auto MAX_CONTENT_SIZE = 512ull << 10; // 512 KiB max payload size

struct Message {
    std::vector<char> _buffer;

    using Uint32 = boost::endian::big_uint32_t;
    struct header_t {
        Uint32 filename_length;
        Uint32 content_size;
    };
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<header_t> and
                  std::is_trivial_v<header_t>);

    Message() = default;

    Message(fs::path file) {
        std::string const name = file.native();
        std::ifstream ifs(file, std::ios::binary);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> data_begin{ifs}, data_end{};

        _buffer.resize(header_len + name.length());
        std::copy(begin(name), end(name), _buffer.data() + header_len);
        _buffer.insert(_buffer.end(), data_begin, data_end);
        header().filename_length = name.length();
        header().content_size    = actual_size() - header_len - name.length();
    }

    Message(char const* buf, size_t size) 
        : _buffer(buf, buf+size) {}

    static constexpr auto header_len = sizeof(header_t);
    static constexpr auto max_size =
        header_len + MAX_FILENAME_LENGH + MAX_CONTENT_SIZE;

    char const* data() const { return _buffer.data(); }
    size_t actual_size() const { return _buffer.size(); }
    size_t decoded_size() const {
        return header().filename_length + header().content_size;
    }
    bool is_complete() const {
        return actual_size() >= header_len && actual_size() >= decoded_size();
    }

    header_t& header() {
        assert(actual_size() >= header_len);
        return *reinterpret_cast<header_t*>(_buffer.data());
    }

    header_t const& header() const {
        assert(actual_size() >= header_len);
        return *reinterpret_cast<header_t const*>(_buffer.data());
    }

    std::string_view filename() const { 
        assert(actual_size() >= header_len + header().filename_length);
        return std::string_view(_buffer.data() + header_len,
                                header().filename_length);
    }

    std::string_view contents() const {
        assert(actual_size() >= decoded_size());

        return std::string_view(_buffer.data() + header_len +
                                    header().filename_length,
                                header().content_size);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Message const& mf) {
        return os << "Name: " << std::quoted(mf.filename())
                  << " content size: " << mf.contents().size();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    u_int16_t port = 8989;

    if (1==argc) {
        std::cout << "Receiving uploaded files: " << std::endl;
        tcp::acceptor acc(ctx, tcp::endpoint{{}, port});

        while (true) {
            auto s = acc.accept();
            std::cout << "Connection accepted from " << s.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            Message msg;
            auto buf = boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(msg._buffer);
            error_code ec;
            while (auto n = read(s, buf, ec)) {
                std::cout << "(read " << n << " bytes, " << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

                while (msg.is_complete()) {
                    std::cout << "Received: " << msg << std::endl;
                    buf.consume(msg.decoded_size() + Message::header_len);
                }
            }
            std::cout << "Connection closed" << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Loading files: " << std::endl;
        tcp::socket s(ctx);
        s.connect(tcp::endpoint{{}, port});

        for (auto file : std::vector<fs::path>{argv + 1, argv + argc}) {
            if (is_regular_file(file)) {
                try {
                    Message encoded(file);
                    std::cout << "Sending: " << encoded << std::endl;

                    write(s, boost::asio::buffer(encoded._buffer));
               } catch (std::system_error const& se) {
                    std::cerr << "Error: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
                } catch (std::exception const& se) {
                    std::cerr << "Other: " << se.what() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

> Note how this easily scales to larger files, multiple files in a single connection and even multiple connections simultaneously if you need. It also doesn't do double buffering, which improves performance.
> This is why this kind of approach is much more usual than any of your other approaches.

Comment: Note that, coincidentally, just to run the demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/113f8ad5b1177c6e) I proved your assumptions about `managed_mapped_file` wrong. The interface for `managed_mapped_file` and `maged_shared_memory` is **identical** so they have identical limitations anyways (they're both manged memory segments). It's important to understand your requirements and limitations before choosing.

Comment: I have two processes: Client and Server. The file will be written by the client. The server only reads this file. Can I define a default constructor: MyFile () = default; to create a file buffer on the server: auto loaded = shm.construct <Shared :: MyFile> ("file1") (). And on the client, call something like this: pair <Shared :: MyFile *, size_t> pMF = shm.find_or_construct <Shared :: MyFile> ("file1") (); and, then, do the initialization of the class fields manually?

Comment: The server is unaware of the file name, size and type.Only the client knows the file name, size and type.

Comment: You're focusing on the "How", I was [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576437/how-to-put-file-in-boostinterprocessmanaged-shared-memory/66607723?noredirect=1#comment117745259_66576437) about the "What" (and perhaps "Why").  This is giving you tunnel vision, so we can't optimally help. See also  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Most likely you don't need shared memory - at all - but rather need a stream protocol (e.g. pipe, UNIX domain or TCP socket). Also, you cannot default-construct any[thing holding a] shared memory allocator, by definition. Finally, I think you're very confused. You seem to want to pass `"file1"` to the segment manager, and somehow have the size_t returned? The whole point of my solution was to keep both inside `MyFile` so that server can "receive" them.

Comment: _(Note that the whole lingo where clients "send" and server "receives" indicates a use-case incompatible with `managed_shared_memory`. A close match would be `message_queue` but even that would likely be extremely inefficient.)_

Comment: According to the terms of reference, I should use shared memory, but not the message queue.

Comment: "The terms of reference". I don't know what that means. Also, the answer shows you how to transfer hundreds of files of varying sizes and name, what else is missing? There's even a live demo.

Comment: Yes, your answer is very good and useful. I agree. And I will be guided by it. And "The terms of reference" is assignment to the programmer for work.

Comment: For comparison, here's a [message queue implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10f5dde5281c0f41) with [demo GIF](https://imgur.com/57e3pp9). Note that there is a filesize limit in this approach because messages have a maximum length

Comment: And for completeness, here's a [TCP socket implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/973a2d92645665ca) with [demo GIF](https://imgur.com/9zwA14m). Note how this easily scales to larger files, multiple files in a single connection and even multiple connections simultaneously if you need. It also doesn't do double buffering, which improves performance.
This is why this kind of approach is much more usual than any of your other approaches.

Comment: In the examples, you use string and char. Can I replace them with wstring and wchar when I do a similar file transfer to shared memory in my application?

Comment: @Prohor have you tried? Of course you can. It will get clumsy because of the length calculations. Use bytes for the contents (because the files should be treated as binary in the general case), It's going to be much simpler with e.g. the sockets based approach, because there's less of a need to cram everything into a byte buffer manually: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6bd89329c575683

Comment: (Just realized `wchar_t` does kill your portability - so you might as well do away with the big-endian length fields. The size of `wchar_t` is implementation defined, so might even vary on a single platform)

Comment: When I try to compile your example with sared memory the following error occurs: C2661 no overloaded function takes 4 arguments boost::interprocess::detail::named_proxy.hpp. I use Visual studio 2019 Community and Boost 1_75_0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229908/discussion-between-sehe-and-prohor).

Comment: [CC from chat] here's [doing it manually without "extra steps"](https://godbolt.org/z/4KGEc7) and here's [magical emplace bliss](https://godbolt.org/z/1d7cjG) all compiling happily on MSVC19/Boost1.75.